# Блокировка Ctrl+Alt+Del через C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

Я нашел на гитхабе вот такой сурс на С++, способный каким-то образом полностью заблокировать сочетания клавиш Ctrl+Alt+Del и Ctrl+Shift+Esc: https://github.com/SweetIceLolly/Disable_Ctrl_Alt_Del

Судя по всему там какой-то трюк с хуками клавиатуры + суспендом процессов.
Я скомпилил, на Windows 8.1 и 10 x64 всё работает отлично. Но я не пишу на С++.
Короче говоря, как мне запустить этот код из С#? Или есть подобный код для С#?
Встраивание скомпилированного exe-файла не предлагать.

Comment: Оказывается, код из вопроса просто суспендит winlogon.exe. И если есть права администратора, это работает.

Comment: Зачем вам понадобилось блокировать эти сочетания клавиш?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov очевидно, чтобы не дать пользователю выйти из системы/выключить компьютер

Comment: А зачем нужно не дать пользователю выйти? Конечная цель какая?

Comment: [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/184217)

Comment: Может вам нужен [kiosk mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)?

Answer (score 2):

Всё это не кодом надо, а через реестр и для конкретного пользователя (автологин на него тоже).
Winlogon/Shell поменять/добавить через реестр.
Winlogon/DisableCAD
Диспетчер задач и Ctrl+Alt+Delete тоже через реестр заблокировать или через групповые/локальные политики.
Либо кодом менять записи в реестре и политике, есть в пространстве имён:
Microsoft.Win32.Registry
Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPDomain //Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли. Мне нужно было не выключить запрос ctrl+alt+del при входе в систему (Winlogon/DisableCAD), а временно отключить эту комбинацию уже в активной сессии. Диспетчер задач можно выключить через реестр, но ctrl+alt+del, насколько я знаю, нельзя. Или можно?

Answer (score 0):

Засуспендив (suspend) winlogon.exe отключаются некоторые горячие клавиши включая Ctrl+Alt+Del и невозможно покинуть сессию Windows. Как суспендить процессы в C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257/suspend-process-in-c-sharp
Проблема решена. /тред

**UPD:** Метод по ссылке выше не работает. Воспользовался Sysinternals pssuspend

Comment: Выглядит как костыль, но если вас устраивает - то ок.

Comment: @aepot Да, это костыль, но другого способа отключить Ctrl Alt Del не существует.

Comment: @aepot А вы знаете еще способы? Я перерыл весь интернет, и нашел только это, причем в виде кода на С++

Comment: Ну как минимум можно переопределить winlogon приложение через реестр, но в последний раз я это делал в XP лет 10 назад. Грубо говоря, то что вам приходится суспендить можно и вовсе не запускать. Ну и ссылка про kiosk mode выше в комментарих под вопросом похожа на то что вам нужно.

Comment: @aepot Не знал. Ок, оба способа имею право на жизнь. А киоск мод нужно настраивать вручную +только на 10 винде.

Comment: Кхм, вообще похоже на винлокер... Но да ладно, я обычно выключаю компьютер через win + r, что вы будете делать с клавишей win?

Comment: @こきん Убью проводник. Винлокер? Мы в 2010?